# How to interpret a statement which enumerates numbers with indices; is there any notion of order between the numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, definition

I am wondering if statements which refer to generic numbers with indices have notions of order between these numbers. As an example of what precisely I am wondering, take this statement:$a_1 \cdot a_2\ldots \cdot a_{n-1}  \cdot 2a_n = 2k $, where $k$ is an integer and $a_1, a_2, \ldots,a_{n-1}, a_{n} $ are natural numbers.

Is it correct to think of this as saying the product of any $n$ numbers where one of them is even is even, or the product of any $n$ numbers where the $n$th number is even is even? I am conflicted because when we have enumerated $a_1, a_2, \ldots,a_{n-1}, a_{n} $ , it seems we have presupposed an order to them by giving them indices, but on the other hand we usually think of numbers as forming sets and sets have no notion of order in them. So which of these 2 ways to think of this example are correct?

Comment: There is no (explicit) relationship between the $2$ and the $a_n$. There is an association between $n$ and $a_n$. Strictly speaking not an order. Although you can consider the natural order $1<2<\ldots<n$ to then speak of and order in which $a_n$ is the last among $a_1, a_2,\ldots,a_n$. Still, the $2$ is outside that picture.

Comment: You can assume an order if you find it is useful to do so, invoking the phrase "*Without Loss of Generality*" if you need to.  The statement you specifically describe in your post could have been made more general by saying "*$a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are all integers where at least one of these is even*" and not specified, but this is not all that different than saying "*$a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ where without loss of generality we have that $a_n$ is even.*"  You should be careful however if these variables were previously named and have other conclusions or assumptions already made about them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read literally, your statement says that the product of any $n$ numbers, where the $n$th number is even, is even.

Since multiplication is commutative, you can immediately deduce from this that the product of any $n$ numbers, where one of them is even, is even.

If multiplication were replaced by some non-commutative operation here, this deduction would not be valid.

Comment: To expand a little: if you're trying to prove the statement "the product of $n$ numbers is even if one of them is even", you could be pedantic and say "choose an ordering of these numbers so that the last number is even", and then prove the statement assuming the last number is even.